# How to hide everything except particular block? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have code:

```
<ul class="smenu">
    <li><a href="#" onClick='age("y031");'>0,3 - 1 год</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#" onClick='age("y12");'>1 - 2 года</a></li>   
    <li><a href="#" onClick='age("y23");'>2 - 3 года</a></li>   
    <li><a href="#" onClick='age("y812");'>8 - 12 лет</a></li>  
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    function age(a) {
        $('.table *[class != a]').hide();
    }
</script>

  <tr class="table">
  <td><span class="y12">test</span></td>
      <td><span class="y23">test</span></td>
      <td><span class="y812">test</span></td>
      <td><span class="y23">test</span></td>
      <td><span class="y031">test</span></td>
  </tr>
```

this code hide all class in .table. How to hide just do not match the classes after clicking the link? Preferably without reloading the page. Thanks!

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Can you clarify using http://translate.google.com? Unfortunately I am unable to determine what you want but I'm more than willing to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you want this:

```
function age(a) {
    $('span').hide(); $('.'+a).show();
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/m57W4/3/)

Comment: @SridharR added the demo

Comment: i know your code not working thats why i told you to add demo

Comment: Actually, it should have worked but I edited my answer

Comment: @SridharR, now it works. But the change is not visible. check the console. Now it works

Comment: Before check dont post here

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function age(a) {
        $('.'+a).show().siblings('span').hide();
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m57W4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<ul class="smenu">
    <li><a href="#" class="y031">0,3 - 1 год</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#" class="y12">1 - 2 года</a></li>   
    <li><a href="#" class="y23">2 - 3 года</a></li>   
    <li><a href="#" class="y812">8 - 12 лет</a></li>  
</ul>

<table>
  <tr class="table">
      <td><span class="y12">test12</span></td>
      <td><span class="y23">test23 </span></td>
      <td><span class="y812">test812</span></td>
      <td><span class="y23">test23</span></td>
      <td><span class="y031">test031</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

// Script
$(".smenu li a").click(function()
{
    var showClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $(".table td span").hide();
    $("." + showClass).show();
});
```

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/anubhavranjan/2WmZV/

Comment: Hope its of some help to you